# FOB holding too much resource materials and vehicles

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have already finished the main story and unlocked all missions.

One thing that bother me most is that my FOB is holding **most of my resources**, let it be processed materials, unprocessed materials or even vehicles. I have > 200k processed fuel but I can only sell **10k** of them for GMP because the remaining are in FOB.

So my question is, is there any way to make sure new resources goes to mother base (so I can sell them), or is there a way to relocate current FOB resources back to mother base?

Comment: I have this issue too. I read in the update news that a November update will allow you to sell materials on FOBs, but I'm curious as to how they got there in the first place.

Comment: I've found that if I just sell as much as I can at once, resources are moved fairly quickly from online to Mother Base to replace what I sold. Any single purchase can be funded in short order, but if you want to start 10 development projects, it could take a while.

Comment: I have also noticed that the ratio of how much I have in MB is somehow consistent, usually MB keeps around 10% of my total resources.
@user2357112 Your method seems promising, I will try it and update you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new update launched today, Nov 11, you can sell supplies located at your FOB.